# How to understand and complete nested loop challenge provided below

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

I need help with this challenge. I feel like I am brain dead when it comes to nesting loops. I had a better understanding of them last semester in a harder Java class than I do in a beginner C class.

[Challenege code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6cuN.png)

Comment: What is it that you do not understand?

Comment: Please know that StackOverflow is not a platform to get your homework done or challenges solved. Show us your code(if you ever tried) and we can help where you have gone wrong.

Comment: Please don't post links to images of challenges, etc.  Include the code (and the challenge) in the question.

Answer (score 1):

That's straightforward. Just use two `for` loops as shown below.

```
for(i=0;i<=userNum;i++) {
   for(j=0;j<i;j++) {
       putchar(' ');
   }
   printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: lol you do not need `prinf("%c", ' ')` delete `%c` completely, this should be `printf (" ")`

Comment: @GRC, yep, fixed it.

Comment: What happened to `putchar(' ');`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, are you saying `putchar` is a better option than `printf`? Well, OP's question is about how to use `for` loops. So this answer tries to address it.

Comment: Once upon another millennium, there were speed advantages to using `putchar()` in place of `printf()` — it could save the overhead of a function call most of the time.  However, it is less than clear that there's a performance benefit these days because of multi-threaded locking etc.  So, the main benefit left to `putchar(' ')` is that it is a direct statement of what your doing, whereas `printf(" ")` is slightly more indirect.  Think of it as an old timer grumbling about the good old days…

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, your point is very well taken. Thanks for a really nice explanation. I have updated my answer.